# Java Input wont work with canvas

Tags: java, graphics, input

I'm making a basic program with Java. I got Input working with this code:

```
package main;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class Input extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
        _press[ke.getKeyCode()] = true;
        _pressed[ke.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
        _press[ke.getKeyCode()] = false;
        _released[ke.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
    public void update(){
        for (int i = 0; i < _press.length; i ++){
            _pressed[i] = false;
            _released[i] = false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * checks if a key is being pressed
     * @param key an integer representing a key(Key class recommended)
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static boolean check(int key){
        if (_press[key]) return true; else return false;
    }
    /**
     * checks if a key was pressed
     * @param key an integer representing a key(Key class recommended)
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static boolean pressed(int key){
        if (_pressed[key]) return true; else return false;
    }
    /**
     * checks if a key was released
     * @param key an integer representing a key(Key class recommended)
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static boolean released(int key){
        if (_released[key]) return true; else return false;
    }
    protected static boolean[] _press = new boolean[128];
    protected static boolean[] _pressed = new boolean[128];
    protected static boolean[] _released = new boolean[128];
}
```

I ran tests, I got a basic entity system working using an ArrayList, all was fine.

But then I ran into graphics.

I set up a Jcanvas class (extends Canvas) but upon adding it to my frame, the graphics will work just fine, but my input no longer works at all.

```
canvas = new Jcanvas();
canvas.setSize(width, height);
canvas.setBackground(Color.RED);
frame.add(canvas);

//input
frame.addKeyListener(new Input());
```

Is there a way to fix this, or will I be stuck with either graphics or input?

Here is my Jcanvas class for reference:

```
package main;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Jcanvas extends Canvas{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    }
    public void drawrect(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        //g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    public void drawfill(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
//input
Input input = new Input();
frame.addKeyListener(input);
canvas.addKeyListener(input);
```